# How to validate Exception in spring-webflux WebTestClient tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

How can I validate the actual `Exception` in a `spring-webflux` test?
The following worked in the old `spring-web` environment, but migrating to netty and spring-webflux, the `MvcResult` cannot be resolved anymore (`NullPointerException`):

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class ApiTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/api?test=123")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest()
                .expectBody().consumeWith(rsp -> {
                     //throws NPE
                    Exception ex = ((MvcResult) rsp.getMockServerResult()).getResolvedException();
                    assertTrue(ex instanceof ResponseStatusException);
                });
    }
}

@RestController 
public class ApiController {
   @PostMapping("/api")
   public String test(@RequestParam String test) {
      if (test.matches("[0-9]+"))
         throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BadRequest, "Prohibited characters");
   }   
}
```

How could I still validate the real exception class?

Comment: What does your migrated code look like (or the original one depending on what you posted here)?

Comment: The original code just has the `@AutoConfigureMvcMock` annotation using `spring-web` dependency. I switched now to `spring-webflux` only. And with this, the `rsp.getMockServerResult()` call always results in `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of the `WebTestClient` is to test endpoints using fluent API to verify responses. There is no magic deserialization or error handling happening but you can get access to the raw responses (status, headers, body).

In your example you will not get `MvcResult` or `ResponseStatusException` but you could get access to the raw body using `rsp.getResponseBody()` that would look like

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-17T17:57:07.041+00:00",
    "path": "/api",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "requestId": "4fa648d"
}
```

You could use `expectBody().consumeWith(rsp -> { ... })` to get access to the request and response or expectBody(String.class).value(body -> { ... })`to get just body. As an alternative use some fluent API to validate result JSON`.expectBody().json()`or`.expectBody().jsonPath()` to check specific fields only.

In addition you could still deserialize body explicitly using `.expectBody(Response.class).value(body -> {...})`.